# Select attribute without id

Tags: linux, xmlstarlet

I am trying to create a script that changes some values in an xml-file. But I can't figure out how to change the ports on this lines as there is no id. Can I somehow select identical elements by order like:

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u "/Connector[1]/@port" -v 9500 server.xml



<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="9000" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" server=" "/>
<Connector port="8029" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
<Connector address="127.0.0.1" connectionTimeout="20000" port="9002" protocol="HTTP/1.1" server=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was very close in my attempt, I was only missing a "/"
this is the correct command in case someone else have the same question.

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u "//Connector[1]/@port" -v 9500 server.xml
```